# libreoffice writer - special char corresponding to indentation

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I must to change using find and replace tool (I'm using the add-on called 'alternative search') a lot of occurrence of a particular word in the beginning of indented lines, like so:
[indentation]Word_to_be_replaced, but I can't make it work. There is a special char corresponding to indentation? I tried \t, \n, \r, etc., but not worked

Comment: Please copy and paste the text with the indentation into the question.  Perhaps there are some hidden characters.

Comment: @JimK I'm using the "Apply Style", "Hanging Indent". Trying to past it in the question, but I saw that it does not indent, but still in the same line of its previous paragraph and looks like a normal space char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the indent is from formatting rather than a [whitespace character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).  So, the word is actually located at the beginning of the line.  To search for a word at this location, simply use `^`, for example:

```
^Word_to_be_replaced
```

Documentation for regular expressions is at https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If the indentation is a tab, then [AltSearch](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer) will accept `\t`.

[image]

But if it is with spaces or other hidden characters then that will not work.  Instead, search for lines that begin with some combination of spaces and tabs:

```
^[\t ]+How
```

The same syntax works with normal Find and Replace as well, as long as the `Regular expressions` box is checked:

[image]

Comment: I tried your explanation, but it does not work. Finally I found that in my case, the indentation isn't a hidden character, so it works just putting the regex `^` to match the begin of the line followed by the word, so: `^Word_to_be_replaced`

Comment: This answer probably isn't the best to accept because it didn't really address the problem.  Instead, I'll summarize what you said in another answer.  Then you can either accept my other answer or else write your own.